# в профиле google chrome есть папка code cache

Tags: google-chrome

в профиле google chrome есть папка code cache.
за что отвечает эта папка? что будет если её удалить...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это папка, в которой находится кэш кода на JavaScript. Если ее удалить, все будет хорошо. Удалить ее можно штатными средствами, нажав Ctrl+Shift+Del и поставив галку только напротив кэша.